# WHy is nginx trying to serve over SSL

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx. So, I know I will need to post additional info. Apologies for starting with a lack of info.

I have my first nginx server set up with virtual domains. The problem domain is a sub-domain with DNS (A record) set up on external nameservers.

When I enter the domain name I am directed to my server's IP, but, through https. The connection is refused. Here is my .conf for the domain:

```
 server {
    listen *:80;


    server_name dev.imageweaversmarketing.com ;

    root   /var/www/dev.imageweaversmarketing.com/web;



    index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

    error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/dev.imageweaversmarketing.com/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/dev.imageweaversmarketing.com/access.log combined;

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
  location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /stats/ {

        index index.html index.php;
        auth_basic "Members Only";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/stats/.htpasswd_stats;
    }

    location ^~ /awstats-icon {
        alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
    }

  location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /stats/ {

        index index.html index.php;
        auth_basic "Members Only";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/stats/.htpasswd_stats;
    }

    location ^~ /awstats-icon {
        alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
    }
  location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files /cdb8ed7968b49bb25b7be537a21b99cb.htm @php;
    }

    location @php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

 }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the external nameserver? Wouldn't happen to be cloudflare would it?

Comment: No. The DNS is GoDaddy

Comment: The access log should explain what is happening. My guess is that your application is doing the redirect.